# Not able to drag and drop an element if sortable is applied on parent and child both in RubaXa Sortable

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, kanban, rubaxa-sortable

```
I created BIN "http://jsbin.com/cekarimaxu/1/edit?html,css,js,output" of my issue.
```

Here, I have a structure like STAGE -> In stage there is a card.

Now card and stage both should be sortable and for sortaable i am using [RubaXa sortable](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable).
Note that Here I set "forcefallback: true" because I want to style my dragged element (Both stage as well as cards).

Now here the issue I am facing is I can drag and drop the cards  but I am not able to drag and drop the stages SEE:- [VIDEO](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fQQFp3Zx_qMqij_6Y8ehGWevZ3kqD08q/view)

The desired behavior should something like this:- [VIDEO](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11k1qI_hzKQOunVAVxGD4eEmLccDFUv5C)

However, this desired behavior comes if I set "forcefallback: false" and in my case, I want to apply some custom CSS on the dragged element so I can't set "forcefallback: false"

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is with how you structured you nested lists.

Your current implementation:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="list-group">Stage -1
        <div class="card">A</div>
        <div class="card">B</div>
        <div class="card">C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group">Stage-2
        <div class="card">D</div>
        <div class="card">E</div>
        <div class="card">F</div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group">Stage-3
        <div class="card">G</div>
        <div class="card">H</div>
        <div class="card">I</div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

What you need to do instead is to nest the child group similarly to how you have the parent group nested. That is, you should only have draggable items in each div. Sorry if that's a bad explanation, but maybe an example would make more sense. Here's how I restructured your list so that it would work:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="list-group">
    <div>Stage - 1</div>
    <div class="child">
      <div class="card">A</div>
      <div class="card">B</div>
      <div class="card">C</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group">
    <div>Stage - 2</div>
    <div class="child">
      <div class="card">D</div>
      <div class="card">E</div>
      <div class="card">F</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group">
    <div>Stage - 3</div>
    <div class="child">
      <div class="card">G</div>
      <div class="card">H</div>
      <div class="card">I</div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Note the addition of the `div.child` elements.

Then you should update your javascript to match this new structure like so:

```
// Select parent group and make sortable
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('parent');
new Sortable(parent[0], {
    group: {
        name: 'parent-group'
    },
    forceFallback: true,
    fallbackClass: 'clone',  
});

// Select our child group and make sortable
var child = document.getElementsByClassName('child')
for(var i = 0;i < child.length;i++) {
    new Sortable(child[i], {
        group: {
            name: 'child-group',
            pull: true,
        },
        forceFallback: true,
        fallbackClass: 'clone_card',  
    });
}
```

This will select the parent group as you originally had it, but now instead of selecting the `.list-group` element, we select the `.child` element which contains the objects we wish to drag.

Here's a live example on jsbin you can look reference:
http://jsbin.com/ronikomabi/edit?html,css,js,output

To address your comment, you need to add a minimum width to the `.child` container so that you you still have a drop zone you can drop items onto even after all items have been removed. I updated the JSbin link with a new version that fixes that issue.

Comment: Hii Xander Luciano,
Thanks for your answer and it is working fine... But if there are no cards in stage then I can't drag and drop cards. SEE:- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qnlgO9zwnnh7kfq0Y4XqrCb_OZz-O5Dx/view

Comment: @VandanShah Whoops, I forgot to add a minimum width to the sortable container. I updated my my answer and link :) Should work fine now. Thanks for the video of the issue, that was super helpful.

Comment: Hii Xander Luciano, I am facing one issue while writing automated testcase to test drag and drop in my project, I posted that issue on github. It would very helpful if you can answer on that issue..

Issue link :- https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/issues/1303
Thanks

Comment: Hii Xander, Can you tell me the reason of why i need that extra mousemove only in stages not in cards if i write autometed testcase for cards it is working with only one mousemove  i don't need any extra mousemove like sages? SEE this BIN :- http://jsbin.com/yutiwafeya/edit?js,output

Comment: @Vandan Shah I'll try to remember to check ~8hrs from now in the morning, but I remember trying to make it work with only one drag and nothing worked. Might try different things tomorrow to figure out the "why." If I forget, just post a question here and tag me in the comments or reply with the link and I'll check it out

Comment: Hii Xander, Have you got any reason of "Why we need that extra mouse move only in stage?"

Comment: Hii Xander,

Also is it possible to implement parent-child drag and drop without adding that extra div, because I am implementing this feature on the existing web app so I can't change the structure of existing application... Please answer this question... I stuck because of this issue
Thank you...